# Call codeigniter helper function in core PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have made a helper class `authentication_helper` in which i have made a single function `varify_session()` that checks session. I am using jquery in which i am using `setTimeout` to call somee function via ajax call but this function's call goes to a core PHP code class, now when i call `varify_session()` in core php then it does not work but when i call in codeigniter class then it work so what should i do to call it in core php code, so that it also check session with 1 setTimeout function.
My helper file is in the directior that is

```
/www
  /sample
    /application
      /helpers
         /authentication_helper
    /controller
      /core_php.php
      /other php clases
```

and the code inside `authentication_helper` is this

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function varify_session(){
    $CI = &get_instance();
    $user_session_id = $CI->session->userdata('logged_in');

    if($user_session_id ==  '') {
        redirect('login');
    }
}
?>
```

### UPDATE

Comment: You need to do what CI does under the hood, include the helper file

Comment: i have include it in autoload file

Comment: But the autoload is for CI...Now, I think you must explain what you mean by "core php", because as I understand it you are referring to a php file _outside_ the framework

Comment: that core php  file is in my controller folder

Comment: u mean i also inclue that helper in core class?

Comment: @DamienPirsy can i include that helper function in my jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Helper files in CodeIgniter are just php files with functions embedded in them. There is nothing specifically "CodeIgniter" about them.

You just need to include that particular file in your "core PHP code class":

```
// inside your core php class
include('path/to/my/ci/application/helper/authentication_helper.php');
```

---

**UPDATE**

OK, after reading through some comments and looking more closely at your question, I've noticed that your structure isn't set up correctly to use CodeIgniter the way it was designed to be used.

My first line of questioning would be:  **"What does the `core_php.php` file actually do? Are you trying to use that as a controller? Or are you just using that as an object?"**

- If you're trying to use it as a controller - then don't. Turn it into an [actual CodeIgniter Controller Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html) by extending `CI_Controller`. Then, you would load the authentication helper like any other helper:  `$this->load->helper('authentication');`
- If you're just using it as an object **(which I assume is the case)**, then place it into your `libraries` folder and call it from within a CodeIgniter loaded file (meaning that you have the CI instance available). After you place that file in the `libraries` folder, you can load it with `$this->load->library('core_php');` -- then you can call a method from that file with: `$this->core_php->method_name();`.  And inside the core_php method that needs it, you'd load the authentication helper with: `$this->load->helper('authentication');`

Setting your files up this way will take advantage of the CodeIgniter loading mechanism and give you access to the CI instance - which was what the problem was when you were getting the `Trying to get property of non-object` error (you were trying to get the CI instance from outside the CI bootstrap).

If this setup doesn't help, then we'll need to see the actual contents of the files in question.

Comment: swatkins thanks for replying me, can u tell me how to make the path to generic so that if i change one server to other so no change is required,i m working on current localhost and my root folder name is `sample` so it will be as like this `http://localhost/sample/application/helper/authentication_helper.php` or any other formate .thanks

Comment: Well, without knowing your server, no. This all depends on **where** your core PHP class is, and where it is in relation to the helper file that you need to include.

Comment: i have edited my question plz view it and then kindly tell me path

Comment: In your setup, you would place the following include in your `core_php.php` file:  `include('../application/helpers/authentication_helper.php');`

Comment: it gives me error that is `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: but when i use this `include('http://localhost/sample/application/helpers/authentication_helper.php');` it gives me this error `No direct script access allowed` it means it load that helper

Comment: Use this in core php `include('../sample/application/helpers/authentication_helper.php');`

Comment: yes it work but still one problem that it is not calling the `varify_session()` function that is inside the helper. by including helper it just include that file so how to call now that function inside the helper class.

Comment: i do this but it gives me this error `<p>Message:  Trying to get property of non-object</p>
<p>Filename: helpers/authentication_helper.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 5</p>`

Comment: The problem is you're trying to mix and match core php with files that rely on the CodeIgniter instance. I'll update my answer with my recommended solution.